# Excel evaluates date as int

Tags: excel

I'm trying to match a date against an array. However, I notice my date is evaluated as an integer.

Instead of =MATCH(20/02/2014;B1:B21;1) it becomes =MATCH(41690;B1:B21;1); and I'm getting an #N/A as a result!

How to get this rectified?

Thanks!

Comment: Excel handles all dates internally as numbers.  41690 is the correct number for 2/20/2014, but sometimes Excel gets confused.  Try wrapping your argument in the DATEVALUE() function.  Also double check that your reference range is considered a 'Date' by excel.

Comment: **=MATCH(DATEVALUE("20/2/2014"),B1:B21,1)**

Comment: As you are using 1 as third argument of MATCH then B1:B21 needs to be sorted ascending.....or are you looking for an exact match? - what's your exact formula, are you using a cell reference as lookup value in MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that dates in your lookup column are actually dates (i.e. 5-digit decimal values in fact, but not text).
2. Use a formula like this:

   =MATCH(DATE(2014,2,20),B1:B21,1)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your lookup range is not formatted as Date, because in whatever format you write a date (dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy or yy/dd/mm) dates should match if written as date.